# Saving image with mongoose

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know there are quite a few threads on this topic already, but unfortunately I didn't find my answer until now. I use angular.js with the example code from http://angular-js.in/image-upload/ to get the image from the client. This part works

Now to the node/mongodb part, here's my backend model:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    avatar: { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
    // ...
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

and my node code:

```
exports.createAvatar = function (req, res) {
  var avatar = {
    data: req.body.data.image, // see below
    contentType: 'image/png'
  }

  models.DUser
    .findById(index.findUserId(req))
    .exec(function (err, user) {
      user.avatar = avatar;
      // ...
      user.save(function (err, user) {/* ... */ });
```

and my angularCtrl:

```
var foo = {
  image: image,
  imageName: image.name,
};

$http.post('/api/users', {data: foo })
    .success(function (result) { /*...*/ });
```

Beside from req.body.data.image I tried many different variations like req.body.data.image.dataURL, req.body.data.image.dataURL.data, but nothing worked so far. My Logging of req.body.data.image shows:

```
{ file: 
   { webkitRelativePath: '',
     lastModified: 1411073963000,
     lastModifiedDate: '2014-09-18T20:59:23.000Z',
     name: '3770316278.png',
     type: 'image/png',
     size: 32493 },
  url: 'blob:http%3A//127.0.0.1%3A3000/cb20debc-8a3a-468f-ab5c-39299f7ec52b',
  dataURL: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACHCAYAAAC.....
```

How can I save the image to the database?

**edit**

I tried to save everything after `base64,` from `req.body.data.image.dataURL` into the avatar like this:

```
var split = req.body.data.image.dataURL.split('base64,');
var type = split[0];
var data = split[1];

var avatar = {
    data: type,
    contentType:'image/png'
};
```

the save message is still:

```
user.avatar = avatar
user.save(function (err, user) {}
```

But I still get the error

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'avatar' of null

---

since my question changed a bit, I'm marking this one as solved, the new question is here: [Displaying Images in Angular.js from MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367611/displaying-images-in-angular-js-from-mongodb)

Comment: so you want to store the Blob data into mongo, or just the path of the image on server?

Comment: I want to store the blob into mongo

Comment: hmmm, the file data might be in your `req.files` object. And refer [`GridFS`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS) for storing binary data in mongo.

Comment: req.files is undefined. I looked at the GridFS doku, but I'm still not sure how I can save binary data into my mongodb

Comment: Looks like the dataURL field has the image data encoded in base64. If you want to store the image data, just store what is after `data:image/png;base64,`, it's a base64 encoded png.

Comment: I tried that that (edited my original post), but it still doesn't work. But what I dont get is - whats the correct way to do this with mongodb/node? Unfortunately I haven't found a working `gridFS` example either

Comment: In your `EDIT`, the user object is `null`. As mentioned in the error.

Comment: thank you, that was a dumb mistake on my part.. I'm still a little bit confused though how storing images in mongodb with node.js is supposed to work now. Splitting the `dataURL` in substrings doesn't sound like the right thing to do for me.

Comment: @Markus I have been trying to figure out how to save images in mongoDB using mongoose and then display them on the front end but Ive been stuck for days. Any chance you could be able to help? I am not even sure whether I saved the images correctly in mongoDB. Heres my question on SO any help will be greatly appreciated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904157/reading-and-displaying-images-from-mongodb-using-gridfs

Comment: "since my question changed a bit, I'm marking this one as solved, the new question is here": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367611/displaying-images-in-angular-js-from-mongodb

Comment: For storing image in mongodb multer is used would you like to use multer? If yes then i can show example.

Comment: You can try this one ```var buffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath or URL,{ encoding: 'base-64' });```  ```user.avatar = buffer``` ```user.save()```

Comment: Storing image on Mongodb is not a good idea. as you will get max 4 MB or so space for single record.
However Mongodb 5.0 have GridFS. you can check that out https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

Answer (score 1):

You know, definitely it's not the best way to save image data on mongo. Instead you can save your image on any directory on your server and save only url of your file, like..

mongoose-model.js

```
avatar : {
    type : String
}
```

and on your main script you should get

```
let avatar_url = '/path/to/uploads/' + req.body.data.image.file.name
```

something like this

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express than you can use express-fileupload middleware to upload files.

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
app.post('/upload', fileUpload, (req, res) => {
  //Now you can use req.files.file to access the file input with name="file"
  user.avatar = {data: req.files.file.data, contentType: req.files.file.mimetype};
  //Now perform user.save
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your issue is not related to the image.

According to your code, the error message `TypeError: Cannot set property 'avatar' of null` means that the variable `user` is `null`.

And `user` is the result of `findById(index.findUserId(req))`.

So you should try to understand why this part is returning `null`.

Answer (score 0):

it is getting repetitive but express does not support img upload so we should do this step:

1. first installing multer or(any thing you like) +plus fs path and sharp (npm module that resize and change the format helps for ease of job

```
const sharp = require("sharp");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");
```

I do suggest to read multer docs
2.we need a form for image upload

```
<form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="avatar" />
</form>
```

3.little set up for route
we have one file so we single method  and we need tmperory destination for saving file i use a folder called upload in root of my project

```
let upload = multer({ dest: "upload/" });
app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res) {

  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any

const buffer = await sharp(
        path.join(__dirname, `../upload/${req.file.filename}`),
      ).png().toBuffer();
 
      const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: "5ffb8e8b5f31732740314c72" },
        { avatar: buffer },
      );
})
```

now with find and update we successfully updated or created a avatar file 
filename is a  random string that the buffer named in that folder

4.go check out your database to see what happened