# Reading and Displaying images from mongoDB using GridFs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I have been able to successfully upload images to mongoDB using GridFs.
Below are images from my database:

[image: MongoLab]

**fs.files:**

[image]

**fs.chunks:**

[image]

Below is the code I used to upload images:

```
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
var gfs = new Grid(mongoose.connection.db);

app.post('/picture', function(req, res) {
 var part = req.files.filefield;

            var writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({
                filename: part.name,
                mode: 'w',
                content_type:part.mimetype
            });


            writeStream.on('close', function() {
                 return res.status(200).send({
                    message: 'Success'
                });
            });

            writeStream.write(part.name);

            writeStream.end();
   });
```

**The Issue:**

I can't seem to figure out how to read this image from mongoDB and display it on the front end in a HTML `<img>` tag.

**I have tried this so far** but it only displays the name of the file:

```
app.get('/picture', function(req, res) {


gfs.files.find({ filename: 'trooper.jpeg' }).toArray(function (err, files) {

    if(files.length===0){
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: 'File not found'
        });
    }

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': files[0].contentType});

    var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
          filename: files[0].filename
    });

    readstream.on('data', function(chunk) {
        res.write(chunk);
    });

    readstream.on('end', function() {
        res.end();        
    });

    readstream.on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('An error occurred!', err);
      throw err;
    });
  });
});
```

I have taken the code above from [here](https://www.codetutorial.io/file-upload-gridfs-mean-stack-meanjs/)

Can anyone please help. Ive been stuck on this for DAYS!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should really be

```
writeStream.write(part.data);
```

not

```
writeStream.write(part.name);
```

Comment: Again thank you for the answer. If i use part.data it comes up with an error on runtime saying cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Any clues?

Comment: You forgot to add `busboy-body-parser` middleware? It is in the tutorial you mentioned: https://www.codetutorial.io/file-upload-gridfs-mean-stack-meanjs/#crayon-56a0ddae56fde861598831