# Display images from GridFs (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs-stream

I am using the following code to read the image file saved in MongoDB using GridFs:

```
app.get('/picture', function(req, res) {

 var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
    filename: 'trooper.jpeg'
 });

 readstream.on('data', function (data) {
  // We got a buffer of data...

 var buf2 = new Buffer(data).toString('base64'); 
 res.send(buf2.toString())
 console.log(buf2.toString());
 console.log(data);
});
  readstream.on('end', function () {
// File finished reading...
});

});
```

The output of **console.log(buff.toString());** is:

```
dHJvb3Blci5qcGVn
```

The output of **console.log(data);** is:

```
<Buffer 74 72 6f 6f 70 65 72 2e 6a 70 65 67>
```

To display the image I did this:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,dHJvb3Blci5qcGVn">
```

**I am unable to read and display the image in html from GridFs MongoDB**

**UPDATE:**

I have tried this:

```
app.get('/picture', function(req, res) {
res.contentType('image/jpeg');
var readstream = gfs.createReadStream('trooper.jpeg');
readstream.pipe(res);

});
```

The output of the above is:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you really need to embed images into page, use pipes as of saintedlama's answer.

`dHJvb3Blci5qcGVn` is base64 encoded string "trooper.jpeg". Please ensure you correctly saved binary data to GridFS at the first instance.

You can [query it directly](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/#additional-resources) and check content of the file stored in the db.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am not sure whether I have saved it correctly. I posted this question which contains the code for my file upload along with images. Could you have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904157/reading-and-displaying-images-from-mongodb-using-gridfs

Comment: Yep, you saved name of the file, not the binary payload. I answered there.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Grid = require("gridfs-stream");
Grid.mongo = mongo; 

router.get("/:filename", function(req, res){ 
        gfs = Grid(db);
        var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({filename: req.params.filename}); 
        readstream.on("error", function(err){
            res.send("No image found with that title"); 
        });
        readstream.pipe(res);
    });
```

This is the perfect solution to get images from gridfs

Comment: can I use this to normal images in bson doucuments?

Answer (score 0):

You can just pipe the GridFS read stream to the response without buffering:

```
app.get('/picture', function(req, res) {
  // Set correct content type first
  res.contentType('image/png');

  fs
    .createReadStream('/tmp/Disneygoofy2012.jpeg')
    .pipe(res);
});
```

I guess the problem of your buffering solution was that you only pass the first byte package you receive from GridFS to res.send.

Comment: First I would say thank you so much for trying to answer my question and help me. I have made the changes you suggested. I am fairly certain I am doing it wrong. Please see the updated question for my changes and output. If you can help me resolve it would amazing as I've been stuck at this for days. Thanks again.